# what is the .js code doing so CPU intense in pupular video players?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, profiling

What is the .js code doing even when video is paused and there is no user interaction?

I noticed this on a Windows 10 Atom Tablet especially when in energy saving mode. the video playback and decoding is nearly down to zero for the CPU, but Javascript itself is exhausting one core.

I checked that with Edge and F12 profiling and I do not quite understand what needs so much "cycles". From my understanding most is UI and DOM Updates, but why is this necessary when nothing happens (no mouse/touch events). Is this simply mandatory or does it depend on the skills of the programmers?

*As example video playback site I checked Youtube, Pluralsight (new player) and channel9 site which is one of the low .js CPU usage players.*

Comment: Which web page are you testing on? Maybe the js for the page is just buggy. In theory when paused a player should do much so this may be a bug in the specific js player.

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov It came to my attention with the new plural sight player. But it seems youtube HTML5 ain't much better. Channel9 is on the other hand a site which uses much less CPU/.js

Comment: there are some pluralsight MVC4 videos for free... just google for it.

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends on the JS implementation itself, and the streaming technology used. For instance in context of adaptive streaming (which is already used by all major players in this business), there is a lot more going on than "just" rendering. Even if the video is paused it is likely, that some background tasks, like buffering, etc. are performed.

If you are interested in adaptive streaming, I suggest to read [this article from Streaming Media](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-is-Adaptive-Streaming-75195.aspx), or [this one](http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2015/06/replacing-flash-adaptive-streaming-and-drm-in-html5/) focused on HTML5 video playback.

Comment: this is not quite the answer I was looking for, as there are indeed video player sites, that seems to have the same feature set, but consume WAY less CPU than others. and my (junior style) profiling showed rather UI related intense CPU cycles than network related....